# Why did Abel choose 6064321219?

Tags: mathematics

In August 1823, Abel wrote a letter to Holmboe with a date:

> Copenhague, l’an $ \sqrt[3]{6064321219} $ (en comptant lafraction d´ecimal).

$ 1823 \frac{215}{365} < \sqrt[3]{6064321219} < 1823 \frac{216}{365} $, so the date would be 1823-08-04 (the 216th day, counting the 1st day as 0).

But why did Abel choose such a number? He could have chosen integer $ n $ between

$$ \left( 1823 \frac{215}{365} \right)^3 < 6064303397 \le n \le 6064330729 < \left( 1823 \frac{216}{365} \right)^3 . $$

Comment: N. H. Abel, "Extraits de quelques lettres a Holmboe." In: L. Sylow and S. Lie (eds.), *Œuvres Complètes de Niels Henrik Abel, Vol. 2*, Christiania (Oslo): Grøndahl & Søn 1881, pp. 254-255 ([Google scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oeuvres_Completes_de_Niels_Henrik_Abel_M/FZeE5MINtNoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA254&printsec=frontcover)): "Copenhague, l'an $\sqrt[3]{6064321219}$ (en comptant la fraction décimal)" A footnote on p. 254 says this equates to August 3rd, but as the fractional part is $\gt \frac{215}{365}$ it actually equates to 3:39pm on August 4th.

Comment: The footnote on the book only says `*) Le 3 août  1823.` but not the time.

Comment: I already referenced the foot note in my previous comment: "A footnote on p. 254 says this equates to August 3rd". The footnote is in error, however. Just do your own calculation, no magic is involved.